# Is there a way to get the exact data needed from my Python Script

Tags: python

My python script fetches data from below website 'http://api.sl.se/api2/deviations.json?key=c7606e4606f642a380f7fdd75d683448' in a text file.
Now my aim is to filter: 'Headers', 'Details', 'FromDateTime', 'UptoDateTime' and 'Updated'

I have tried BS with text specific search, but not there...Below code shows that. Any help will be indeed helpful :)Sorry if I missed something very natural..

```
'''
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd
import csv
import operator
from numpy import *


# Collect and parse first page

page = requests.get('http://api.sl.se/api2/deviations.json?    

key=c7606e4606f642a380f7fdd75d683448')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

#print(soup)


for script in
     soup(["Header","Details","Updated","UpToDateTime","FromDateTime"]):
script.extract()

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

f1 = open(data.txt", "r") 

resultFile = open("out.csv", "wb")
wr = csv.writer(resultFile, quotechar=',') 
'''
```

I expect a csv with columns of Header","Details","Updated","UpToDateTime","FromDateTime"

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing in a wrong way. You don't need a beautifulsoup for this task. Your api returning data as json. BeautifulSoup is best for html. For your purpose you can use **PANDAS** and **JSON** Library.

Pandas can read directly from webresource as well but you want only requestdata from json so that you require both library.

Here is a snippet which you can use :

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
page = requests.get('http://api.sl.se/api2/deviations.json?key=c7606e4606f642a380f7fdd75d683448')
data = json.loads(page.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(data["ResponseData"])
df.to_csv("file path")
```

Change File path and you get whole data inside csv.

But if you want to remove any column or any manipulation over data you can do using pandas dataframe as well. It is very powerful library you can learn about it using google.

Comment: Thanks Naitik, It did help me getting data in CSV..Though came across the fact that as the data is in Swedish language, I get special characters in my CSV..How can I make sure that I get data in English..Well the website has an option of 'Translate to English' but how do I incorporate it to my script? Thanks

Comment: You can try that using selenium and get text using it or you can use google translate api from python as well

Comment: Ok Naitik, Thank you! will try with Google translate API. Searching for it